# Fluid mechanics -Question about boundary?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

***Problem statement:***

A two-dimensional fluid stream of thickness $S$ and velocity $c$ (evenly distributed through the thickness of the stream) falls on a stationary plate and gets separated. Calculate the ratio of thicknesses $\frac{S_1}{S_2}$ as a function of the angle $\phi$.

[image]

***My question:***

In my notes there is this solution:

Continuity equation:

Let $c_1$, $c_2$ the velocities of the sections 1, 2

$$0: \overrightarrow{u}_0=c\hat{e} \ \ , \ \ \overrightarrow{n}_0=-\hat{e}=-(-\sin \phi \hat{i}+\cos \phi \hat{j}) \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{u}_0 \cdot \overrightarrow{n}_0=-c \\ 1: \overrightarrow{u}_1=c_1 \overrightarrow{n}_1=c_1 \hat{i} \ \ , \ \ \overrightarrow{n}_1=\hat{i} \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{u}_1 \cdot \overrightarrow{n}_1=c_1 \\ 2: \overrightarrow{u}_2=c_2 \overrightarrow{n}_2=-c_2\hat{i} \ \ , \ \ \overrightarrow{n}_2=-\hat{i} \Rightarrow \overrightarrow{u}_2 \cdot \overrightarrow{n}_2=c_2$$

$$\int_{\partial{W_1}}\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n}dA=0 \Rightarrow -c \cdot (S \cdot 1)+c_1 \cdot (S_1 \cdot 1)+c_2 \cdot (S_2 \cdot 1)=0 \Rightarrow cS=c_1S+c_2S_2 \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$

Conservation of energy $\Rightarrow $ Bernoulli equation

$$\frac{1}{2}|\overrightarrow{u}|^2+\frac{p}{\rho_ 0}=\text{ constant along a streamline }$$

$$0 \rightarrow 1 : \frac{1}{2}c^2+\frac{p_a}{\rho_0}=\frac{1}{2}c_1^ 2+\frac{p_a}{\rho_0} \Rightarrow c_1=c \\ 0 \rightarrow 2 : \frac{1}{2}c^2+\frac{p_a}{\rho_0}=\frac{1}{2}c_2^ 2+\frac{p_a}{\rho_0} \Rightarrow c_2=c \\ \Rightarrow c_1=c_2=c \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

$$(1) \wedge (2) \Rightarrow S=S_1+S_2 \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

$$\overrightarrow{F}_{W_0}=-\int_{\partial_{W_1}}p \overrightarrow{n} dA-\int_{\partial{W_1}}\rho \overrightarrow{u} (\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n})dA$$

$$\int_{\partial_{W_1}}p \overrightarrow{n} dA=p_a \int_{\partial{W_1}}\overrightarrow{n}dA=0$$

$$\int_{\partial{W_1}}\rho \overrightarrow{u} (\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n})dA=\rho_0 (c \hat{e}(-c)S+c_1 \hat{i}c_1S_1+(-c_2 \hat{i})c_2S_2)=(\rho_0c^2S\cos \phi +\rho_0 c_1^2S_1-\rho_0c_2^2S_2)\hat{i}-\rho c^2S\sin \phi \hat{j}=-\overrightarrow{F}_{W_0}$$

$$F_{W_0, x}=-\rho_0c^2(S\cos \phi +S_1-S_2) \ \ \ \ \ (4a) \\ F_{W_0, y}=\rho c^2 S \sin \phi \ \ \ \ \ (4b)$$

Since the fluid is ideal we have that $$F_{W_0, x}=0 \Rightarrow S_2-S_1=S \cos \phi \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$

$$(3) \wedge (5) \Rightarrow \\S_1=\frac{S}{2}(1+\cos \phi) \\ S_2=\frac{S}{2}(1-\cos \phi) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{S_2}{S_1}=\frac{1-\cos \phi}{1+\cos \phi}$$

Could you explain to me the general idea of the solution?? I haven't really understood that...Every time when we have such an exercise do we have to use the continuity equation and the Bernoulli equation??

What is the significance of the boundary shown by the  red shape??

Also could you explain to me why the following equality stands??

$$\int_{\partial{W_1}}\rho \overrightarrow{u} (\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n})dA=\rho_0 (c \hat{e}(-c)S+c_1 \hat{i}c_1S_1+(-c_2 \hat{i})c_2S_2)$$

Comment: I'm wondering if a hydraulic effect would be involved.  It seems likely.  It would make the S1 and S2 thicknesses thinner than expected. Do you need to find the thicknesses all along the plate?

Comment: Is picture rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: I don't have to find the thiknesses... I have to find just their ratio... Why do you think that the picture is rotated 90 degrees? @Jiminion

Comment: Because it is 'falling' horizontally.

Comment: The picture at the exercise is as I have it in my initial post... I haven't rotated it... @Jiminion

Comment: @Jiminion Assume it's happening in space

Comment: The last question, equality stands because along the boundary the velocity is constant which means the integrand is constant with respect to dA, hence the vectors can come out of the integral, the integral is over the area the fluid takes up crossing the boundary which is just the thickness of the streams

Comment: If there is no gravity, what holds the fluid on the plate?

Comment: @Jiminion The fluid is propelled towards the plate, which deflects it.

Comment: @Dan Could you explain to me further the part "the area the fluid takes up crossing the boundary which is just the thickness of the streams" ??

Comment: The idea is that the integration limits only cover the part of the bounding surface (called by some a control volume), across wgich the fluid travels. Imagine the simpler case that the boundary is the unit cube with a corner at the origin...each face can be described by inequalities in each variable, here the integrand involves a dot product with velocity and the outward normal, since the velocity is only nonzero where there are fluid particles, the limits of the integration only exist where there is fluid crossing the boundary.

Comment: Is the reason why it stands that $$\int_{\partial{W_1}} \overrightarrow{n}dA=0$$ the same ?? @Dan

Comment: No it is because either u is zero or the dot product is, outside the fluid, in this case u is zero for the integral outside where the fluid is, i have written up a small sketch i will give a link to it shortly